# How should I interpret these ACF / PACF plots for a time series?

Tags: r, time-series, data-visualization, arima, acf-pacf

I am trying to determine the most appropriate degree of difference to start building an arima model for this dataset. I already know that I need a first difference, but there is a seasonal component, and I am not exactly sure where to go from here. I've tried several potential options but I am just not very confident when interpreting these plots. I will include the raw time series plot / acf / pacf plots as well as the first differenced time series / acf / pacf plots. Any help would be fantastic!!

Original:

Time series:

[image: Time series]

acf:

[image: acf]

pacf:

[image: pacf]

First Difference:

[image: first diff time series]

First diff acf:

[image: first diff acf]

First diff pacf:

[image: first diff pacf]

Comment: What's the frequency of the data (e.g. quarterly, monthly)?

Comment: The data is monthly